# How could you recreate the List.iter function in ocaml?

Tags: list, ocaml

I'm quite new to the Ocaml language and in general a newbie in programming. So I feel like this question is very basic but here it is:
I would like to recreate the `List.iter` function in Ocaml to understand it better and because I've been asked to by my teacher. 
Here's what I've done :

```
let rec iter f = function
|[]->()
|e::q-> f e (iter f q);;
```

My two very simple problems are

1. I don't really understand how `List.iter` works
2. this results in ('a -> unit -> unit) -> 'a list -> unit =  and I know my 'f' should only be a
   'a->unit and I don't know how to change it

(If I made any mistakes, I'm sorry, my native language is french)

Comment: OCaml is open source, you can look up the definition directly :-) hope this helps https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/58f8284acae7790511a12f9d481def5e0f8e2abb/stdlib/list.ml#L108

Answer (score 2):

The definition of `List.iter` is something like this. This function call:

```
List.iter f [x1; x2; ...; xn]
```

is equivalent to these separate calls:

```
f x1;
f x2;
. . .
f xn
```

Your problem is mostly that you're missing a semicolon (`;`) to separate statments that should be done sequentially.

This expression:

```
f e (iter f q)
```

is one big expression that calls `f` with three parameters. You need to separate it into its two parts.

Comment: One of the hardest things to get used to in OCaml is the sequence operator(;). Spend some time on it now and save yourself hours of headaches in the future.

Comment: Just a note about the sequence operator.. The concepts behind it are very simple and shouldn't take more than an hour to understand.